# How make Git ignore subdirectories which are git repositories?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I've a git repository folder in which I clone other git repositories. How can the main repo ignore sub-repositories in `git add -A` command?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using git submodules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unstage files

```
git reset HEAD
```

and clean index

```
git rm --cached -r repo1
```

add repo1 as a submodule, create a file .gitmodules contains below

```
[submodule "repo1"]
      path = repo1
      url = git://xx.com/repo1.gitt
```

More about [git cache, stage and index](http://raflabs.com/blogs/silence-is-foo/2011/04/07/staging-area-index-cache-git/)

Answer (score 2):

A nested git repo will be "ignored" by default by any git add made in the enclosing repo.
Actually, as explained in "[Git repository in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980960/git-repository-in-a-git-repository)", the parent rpeo would track the nested git repo state through a [`gitlink`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fast-import.html#_tt_filemodify_tt).

But you shouldn't need to ignore explicitly anything when doing your `git add -A` command.

Answer (score 1):

use git ignore for the folders where the repository is located

.gitignore file:

bin
folderA
picture.png

for example