# gitignore is not ignoring one specific folder

Tags: git, gitignore

Using msysgit on windows:
git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0

I have a folder tree with hundreds of small projects like this:

```
Root
|--Project1
    |--xx/xx/xx/xx/obj
|--Project2
    |--yy/yy/yy/yy/obj
|--Project3
    |--zz/zz/zz/zz/obj
```

I have the entry obj/ in my .gitignore file

One single obj folder is not being ignored and always appears in the untracked files list. I have tried commands such as:

```
git rm -r --cached Project3\zz\zz\zz\zz\obj
```

but it just says pathspec did not match any files - of course it would as the files are not tracked in my git repository.. they're just in the local folder.

How can I ignore this folder?

Comment: Maybe try without the `-r`

Comment: Perhaps that one `obj` folder has at least one file under it that is currently being tracked...

Comment: -r doesn't make a difference and there are no tracked files under the obj folder

Answer (score 0):

Try again with a recent (2018, 4 years later) version of Git.

If there is a file in that `obj/`, you can check if it is ignored or not with:

```
git check-ignore -v --  Project3\zz\zz\zz\zz\obj\aFile
```

Check also if [one of the parent folder is not a gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981099/6309) (root entry for a nested Git repo, or a submodule)

```
git ls-tree HEAD Project3
git ls-tree HEAD Project3/zz
...
git ls-tree HEAD Project3/zz/zz/zz/zz/obj
```

If any of those commands yields 160000, that would mean an [entry to be removed as I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35940796/6309).