# Git - How to remove untracked folder in submodules

Tags: git

I tried checkout and discard this library with git checkout command, but seems it does not work for me.

I tried to remove this folder, but after that git wants me to add this deleted folder to a commit, but I don't want to track it or push to server.

> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add ..." to update
>   what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory)   (commit or discard the untracked or
>   modified content in submodules)
>
> modified:   Libraries/some_sdk (untracked content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to go in that submodule folder and do in it:

```
cd /path/to/repo
cd  Libraries/some_sdk
git reset --hard
```

That should reset its index.

Then, a `git status` from its parent repo should mention the (submodule) folder anymore.

> I don't want to track it or push to server.

It won't be tracked from the parent repo: said parent repo only references the [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) representing the SHA1 of the submodule repo.

> I tried to remove this folder, but after that git wants me to add this deleted folder to a commit

To remove a submodule, see "[How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309)"

```
cd /path/to/repo
git submodule deinit Libraries/some_sdk
git rm Libraries/some_sdk
# note: no trailing slash
rm -rf .git/modules/Libraries/some_sdk
```

Comment: thanks for answer even after `git reset --hard` terminal still shows the same

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander where did you do the git reset --hard? And what a git status return when done from within the submodule?

Comment: I did it in the some_dk directory. `git submodule deinit -f` works for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by deleting the folder git wants to "delete" the changes. It's because it's already been tracked. You can remove them with

`git rm -r [path to dir]`

In the case they were not tracked

`git clean -df` would do the trick (you can use the -n flag instead of -f for a dry-run that would tell you which files would be removed.