# When did Git stop automatically treating nested repositories as simple subdirectories and is this behavior supported in any way anymore?

Tags: git

So I know about git submodules and subtrees. But I also used to be able to have nested full Git repositories treated as nothing simple filesystem subdirectories?

For example, given:

```
topdir/
    file1
    file2
    subdir1/
        file1
        file2
    subdir2/
        file1
        file2
    subdir3/
        .git/
        file1
        file2
```

Previously, simply executing:

```
$ git init && git commit -a .
```

in `topdir` would result in the files of `subdir3` being committed as a raw or literal subdirectory (i.e. *not* a submodule), with the '.git' directory in the subdirectory ignored in the super- or top-level repository. Entering `subdir3` would make `subdir3/.git` to current repository.

With 1.8.2.1.501, there does not seem to be any way to get this behavior back. Running the above command now results in `subdir3` being considered a submodule but, perversely *not* added to the index. I have to explicitly do a `git submodule add` to add the files under it to the main repo.

When did this change happen?

Is there any way to get the old behavior back, i.e., have the subdirectory treated as a regular directory, and not a git submodule or subtree?

Comment: Nested git repos have always been ignored, beside a gitlink, no? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5981099/6309 (2011)

Comment: EDIT: Ok, maybe they were tracked through the mechanism described above. But that has changed? OLD:I definitely have repos with nested git repos treated as regular directories on my filesystem. When these are cloned, the nested repos do not show up as Git repos in the clone (i.e., there is no `.git` sub-directory in what were the nested repos in the original). I cannot figure out how to tell which version of Git created these repos originally, though.

Comment: I don't think *any* git version would allow this, the closest being a merge subtree.

Comment: Any clues ? I need this (git treat nested git repos as plain old directories)