# add link to submodule in pushed repository

Tags: git

I have a repository which now I want to use it as a library inside another repository, so first I cloned it in my project, then pushed my project to my repository, but as you see in the image, there is no way to open `RF24` library from the repo.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just add a nested repo, [its HEAD is recorded as a gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981099/6309), but the parent repo does not know where to look for that repo.

You need to add RF24 as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

```
cd /path/to/parent/repo
git rm RF24
git add -A .
git commit -m "Removes nested repo"
```

Then the parent repo on GitHub would [display `RF24` as a gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)), this time referencing a SHA1 of the `RF24` repo.
Then:

```
git submodule add -- https://url/to/RF24
git add .
git commit -m "Add RF24 as a submodule"
git push
```