# I make a commit in git and get only one file changed and one insertion

Tags: git, bitbucket

I don't know why but it won't add the files in the folder I'm trying to add.

here's what I get

```
$ git commit -m 'come on'
[master (root-commit) fed7d44] come on
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 160000 issp
```

There's many more than one file I want to upload.

I had tried the following before in order to add everything I tried:

```
it rm -f --cached issp
```

The result was nothing, I'm still getting the same errors.

I also tried the following commands:

```
git submodule update --init
```

And then tried to clone again using the following command

```
git clone --recursive my-repo-or-whatever
```

And got the following output for both

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'issp'
```

and:

```
Cloning into 'issrep'...
Password for 'https://pablo-r4001@bitbucket.org': 
remote: Counting objects: 2, done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'issp'
```

No idea what to do about this. are these submodules really even necesary? I was just trying to add a folder to the cloned repo.

I'm desperate, any help is much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`issp` must be a nested repo: adding and committing will create a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)). See more at "[Git repository in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981099/6309)".

But it is not a submodule.

`issrep` is a submodule (registered both as a gitlink in the index *and* in the `.gitmodules`)

So check if the folder you want to add and commit (`issp`) doesn't already include `.git` folder in it: that would make it a nested repo.

Comment: This soundslike a reasonable possibility

Comment: It was exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.