# Code has disappeared from bitbucket repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have an issue and I am not sure what is happening. I have a repository on bitbucket that only I use, and I have only done simple pushes of my code. When I got on today my code in one of my directories is missing. Replaced with this:

Well I can't post pictures, but this is the text that is where my files are supposed to be:

```
DualLoops → 8635cc0a2c54 [8635cc0a2c54]
```

Where my code might have gone off to?

Comment: I think , this is better to post , bit bucket support team. if you don't do any  think , it should be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the directory you thought you `git add`'ed and `git commit`'ed was a nested git repo (meaning a folder with a `.git` subfolder in it).

When you add a nested git repo, the main parent repo records a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309), usually used for [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)).
See more with "[Git repository in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981099/6309)".

Comment: Thank you! This is what had happened now that you point that out. Well...That's a lesson learned the hard way.