# Clone git repo inside another repo (and don't treat the cloned one as a submodule)

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-submodules

In a previous project I was able to clone a third party GIT repo into my project repo. I then added the cloned repo and committed the changes to my project repo. That way I was able to keep the cloned repo up to date via `git pull` in the cloned repo folder, and also able to modify files in it and to commit them to my own project repo.

I have tried to replicate this in a new project and I am facing a strange issue. Basically I follow the same steps (in this case the cloned repo is another project of mine) but when I add the cloned repo files to my own repo, the main repo recognizes the cloned one as a submodule (though no `.gitmodules` file is generated).

I compared the all the git related files and found no difference between the previous project and the current one. Then I cloned the same third party repo I used in the previous project (https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.git) and I was able modify/add files and to commit them to my own repo. 
I can't see any difference between the third party repo I clone and my own project so I can't understand why the latter is treated as a submodule but the first isn't. Any ideas?

Comment: This might have some useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5981099/1615903

Comment: You mean something like this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another