# Two exclusive respositories in one directory git

Tags: git

For an IC design class I am taking we have to VNC into a linux server to access the tools and design out circuitry and test benches. Originally I just had one repository that I was pushing everything to but we have started working on a project in groups and the best way to distribute the designs among everyone appears to be through Git. I need a way to separate my class directory into two separate repositories.

### File Structure

```
class
├── Lib
|   ├── inverter
|   ├── nand2
|   ├── nor2
|   └── proj
└── LibTest
    ├── inverter
    ├── nand2
    ├── nor2
    └── proj
```

#### Desired Project Repository

```
class
├── Lib
|   └── proj
└── LibTest
    └── proj
```

#### Desired Lab Repository

```
class
├── Lib
|   ├── inverter
|   ├── nand2
|   └── nor2
└── LibTest
    ├── inverter
    ├── nand2
    └── nor2
```

I can't really find a way to make this happen unless maybe I have my main repository in the `class` directory and create two separate repositories for `Lib\proj` and `\LibTest\proj` but I would really like it if the two project directories were tied together, as if they were in the same repository.

## Update

*2016-12-02 02:10 PM CST*

Okay, so I setup two separate git repositories within class and renamed them to `.gitproj` & `.gitlab`.

```
git init
mv .git .gitlab
git init
mv .git .gitproj
```

I then modified the `/info/exclude` file to exclude those directories and isolate the lab directories within the lab repo and the proj directory within the proj repo.

#### .gitlab/info/exclude

```
# Ignore git directories
.git*
!.gitignore

# Ignore project directories
Lib/proj
LibTest/proj
```

#### .gitproj/info/exclude

```
# Ignore git directories
.git*
!.gitignore

# Ignore everything under Lib and LibTest
Lib/*
LibTest/*

# Unignore proj directories
!Lib/proj
!LibTest/proj
```

Finally, I added aliases to my .bashrc file. Using Git-Bash for Windows it was the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file.

```
alias gitl='git --git-dir=.gitlab'
alias gitp='git --git-dir=.gitproj'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git repository in a git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980960/git-repository-in-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you run repository actions git performs a lookup for `.git` subdirectory of git process directory. So putting `.git` dir anywhere under `class` directory doesn't fit you case.
But there's a way to tell git use custom `.git` directory anywhere on your file system my passing it's path via environment variable `GIT_DIR`.

So I would do this:

1. Create a root repository of your project, lets name it `root`.
2. Create two repositories like a `root/Project` and `root/Lab` and your sources `root/class`. So far there are `root/Project/.git` and `root/Lab/.git` but no any `.git` subdirectory could be found in `root/class`
3. Make `GIT_DIR=<path-to-root>/Project git add <file>` for Project repository files. Then commit it `GIT_DIR=<path-to-root>/Project git commit -m "Initialise Project repo"`
4. Make `GIT_DIR=<path-to-root>/Lab git add <file>` for Labs repository files and commit the same way.

You always have to provide correct `GIT_DIR` variable every time you call git.
It's a bit tricky to remember which repo file belongs to but that's what you want :)

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post with the solution I came up with. It's fairly similar to yours with the exception of where the repositories are actually located.