# Bitbucket adds only the folders - not the files in them

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to push two folders to a repo on Bitbucket but when I commit I get the following (I did add and commit previously):

```
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 160000 folder2
 create mode 160000 folder1
```

What is that code before folder 2 and 1? Why is it that the files contained in the folder are not being pushed, only the folder names itself?

Comment: Did you *add* and *commit* the files in those folders? You push commits, not files, so unless you added and committed them locally first, git doesn't track them.

Comment: The modes listed are unix file/folder attributes, which git tracks, even though you're on different operating systems. Usually you can ignore those bits.

Comment: Yes, I added both "git add ." and "git commit -m "comment""

Answer (score 2):

> Notice the 160000 mode [...]. That is a special
>   mode in Git that basically means you’re recording a commit as a
>   directory entry rather than a subdirectory or a file.

From [Git Tools - Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). It looks like you added submodules in those folders.

Git does not track folders, it just tracks files and their locations. Folders are stored implicity; if a file exists in a `/source` folder, there has to be folder named `source` (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115992/7598462)).

What exactly were your steps to get into this state?

Comment: git init, git add ., git commit -m "comment"

Comment: Are there other repositories in those folders? I could reconstruct your situation when the folders contain git repositories themselves. In this case, git creates a gitlink to those repositories instead of adding the contents (files) of the other repository.

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5981099/7598462) that describes details about nested repositories and seems to fit to your problem.

Comment: thanks so much it worked